# How can I enumerate all the file in a directory in POSIX/c c++?

Tags: c++, c, unix, posix, vfs

I need to enumarate all the file in a dir and then navigate to the subdir and do the same.

Ideally the algorithm should work in the same way on linux macos [windows(obsolete) no more].

UPDATE: I'm now aware of VFS but I'm puzzled to use VFS for enumerate dir. Any suggestion ? Should I open a dir as file ?

Comment: MS Windows is not POSIX-conforming, but you may be able to use cygwin to overcome this, and the same GNU library will do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX.1-2001 specifies `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir`, `seekdir`, `rewinddir`, and `telldir`.  Your platform likely has man pages describing how to use them.

These are reportedly not supported directly by MS libraries, instead apparently preferring to use `FindFirst` and `FindNext` over there, but there's supposedly several emulation libraries that provide the above; you'll have to sort that part on your own, as I'm not very familiar with Win32.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using GCC, you can try the file system interface.
Check out here: [GNU file system interface referemce](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-System-Interface.html#File-System-Interface)

Comment: Most of those functions are standard, as stated by @Sdaz's post, so they are not GNU-only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm), which is portable to Linux, Windows, and MacOS. The [recursive_directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator) will allow you, as the name implies, to iterate recursively through a directory.

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator end;
    for ( fs::recursive_directory_iterator dir("./"); dir != end; ++dir )
    {
       std::cout << *dir << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: not exactly what I asked but it's pointing me to a interesting alternative! cool

Answer (score 1):

You should use getdents() or readdir() on Linux